# Prevent disk read/write access between 2 operating systems

Tags: partitioning, virtual-machine, virtualization, operating-systems, disk-encryption

I would like to isolate disks between 2 operating systems. I hope im posting on the correct stackexchange :)

Setup:

- 1x 2.5 SATA drive with work OS - im not in control of the settings in
  this OS
- 1x 2.5 SATA drive with personal OS - im in control here, but lets if say ransomware takes control here i dont want it to affect the work drive at all
- 1x M.2 NVME drive with personal data

I want to prevent read/write from work OS to both personal drives.
I want to prevent read/write from personal OS to work drive.

My motherboard BIOS cant disable the drives (not even just the 2.5 SATA drives). I cant use SATA power switch like this one https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000601282955.html because one of the drives is M.2.

What are the ways to solve this while keeping as much of the performance as possible? Maybe some kind of virtualization? - just wondering, dont let this pigeonhole you into a solution

Comment: So you have a dual boot ? Need a little more info.

Comment: If you were to virtualize a personal OS within your work OS (and you can store the virtual disk on whatever disk you want), should something happen in the VM OS, it would not affect the host (i.e. work) OS. Alternatively, if you are doing a dual boot, simply install the personal OS on the non-work drive and within Windows on the personal drive, go to disk management and remove drive letters from the work disk (and do the same in your work OS but instead remove the personal disk letters). This should protect you from accessing the other disk when booted into your desired OS.

Comment: Ransomware has been honed to cross and connected system borders, so your task is very difficult, if even possible.  Good, totally not connected, backups are essential.

Comment: However, if you were to contract a malicious virus, I am not sure that disabling drive letters is sufficient to protect against a virus. In fact, if the virus operates at a low-level, it may be destructive for all drives.

I would like someone else to chime in to confirm or correct these "solutions"

Comment: If you have no control over the OS, then virtualization would not be possible. For VM to work, you would need to install in on the host (work) OS and configure it from there.

Comment: its not a classic dual boot, each OS disk has its own boot loader that shouldnt know anything about the other OS. virtualizing personal OS from the work OS (or the other way) also means the host has read/write over the virtualized OS which also isnt safe

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to encrypt your personal OS with
full-disk encryption.

As it then won't be possible to mount it without a password/key,
the work OS couldn't read it,
but could still destroy it by
overwrite.

The only way to fully protect the
disk would be to physically disconnect it.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I see is with Virtual Machines.

If you have say oracle virtual box, or vmware esxi, or workstation.

Each virtual machine is isolated from each other.

The host could see both VM's but it would not mount them and neither VM would see the others storage space.

Encryption could be used on each VM as an additional layer of security.

You would just have to configure the firewall to block connections from one VM to another.  None are setup by default, but obviously windows file and printer sharing could be turn on.

You could have a 3rd much smaller VM to act as a firewall between the 2 networks.